# How can I Access _id field on djongo model it returns None

Tags: django, djongo

This code creates a User document
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

```
def create_user(self, name, email, password, mobile_number, alias=None):
    user = self.model(email=self.normalize_email(email))
    user.name = name
    user.mobile_number = mobile_number
    user.set_password(password)
    user.save()
    return user

def create_superuser(self, email, password):
    user = self.create_user(email, password)
    user.is_staff()
    user.is_superuser = True
    user.save()
    return user
```

This is the User Model it uses the **djongo** models classes

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
_id: ObjectIdField(primary_key=True)
email = EmailField(null=False, unique=True)
name = CharField(max_length=30)
mobile_number = CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)
is_active = BooleanField(default=True)
is_staff = BooleanField(default=False)

objects = UserManager()
USERNAME_FIELD = "email"

class Meta:
    db_table = "login"

user = User()
user.email = 'test@mail.com
user.name = 'name'
user_mobile_number = '7894561236'
user.save()
```

> > print(user._id)
> > ->None
> > accessing user id this way returns None

```
user.name = 'newname'
user.save() #this creates a new instance of document
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not implicitly create a _id. Creation of the _id field is usually provided by MongoDB server ([docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#the-_id-field)). So with your code, you can only retrieve inserted object and get it's _id value.

```
User.objects.filter(email = 'test@mail.com').first()._id
```

If you would like to have the _id value before insert, then you need to create it using bson.objectid.ObjectId class. You can create a new unique identifier or create custom one. But keep in mind that the ObjectId oid parameter can be only an ObjectId, or any 12 bytes.
[Tools for working with ObjectIds in pymongo](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/bson/objectid.html)

```
from bson.objectid import ObjectId
user._id = ObjectId(b'123456789012') # or ObjectId()
```